# How to read specific atomic coordinates from a PDB file using C

Tags: c, protein-database

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *pdb;
    pdb=fopen("5an3.pdb", "r");
    if(feof(pdb))
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"File reading error!!! Probably your PDB file doesn't contain anything or poorly formatted\n");      
        return 0;
    }
    char test[255];
    while(!feof(pdb))
    {   
        fgets(test, 255, (FILE*)pdb);
        char check[10];
        strncpy(check,test,4);
        if(strcmp(check,"ATOM")==0)
        {
            char resname[3];
            strncpy(resname,&test[17],3);
            if((strstr(resname,"THR"))||(strstr(resname,"TYR"))||(strstr(resname,"PHE"))||(strstr(resname,"TRP")))
            {
                printf("%s\n",test);
            }
            else
            {
                printf("No Aromatic Residues Found!!! Better luck next time!!!\n");
                return 0;
            }
        }           
    }
    fclose(pdb);
    return 0;
}
```

I tried to retrieve the records which have THR, PHE, TYR, TRP and the coordinates of their atoms for further processing. But, it seems that there are lots of invisible ascii characters in the pdb file which botch up everything. How to get rid of this?

Comment: I suppose that your file is in UTF-8

Comment: may be... but, how to handle that?

Comment: you can get the file here... and you can run the code yourself...

http://www.rcsb.org/pdb/explore/explore.do?structureId=5an3

Comment: It's hard in C, you need to use a library. you should try in python language, it's more easy.

Comment: I know it's hard in C, but we need to use C for a specific purpose (to meet a specific requirement)... So...